# Code Coverage for UI Functional Testing on Angular JS application

Tags: angularjs, code-coverage, e2e-testing, istanbul, testcomplete

We are using Smartbear TestComplete tool to automate our Angular JS application. Now we are looking to measure our UI functional testing code coverage. We dont find a way to do it.
We tried using istanbul but it didnt work.
Can anybody please help.

Note: If any plugin available which can serve the purpose would also do the job.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The typical way of tracking End-to-End test coverage is to establish a mapping or matrix from requirements, through development tasks and on to testing. For example;

```
Requirement: Create a login page
-> Task: Develop the login page
   -> Test: User can log in
   -> Test: User can't log in with invalid credentials
   -> Test: User can log in with different personas
   -> Test: ...
```

This is usually handled with a project management or test management solution, for example Jira + Zephyr Enterprise, where the test definitions and outcomes can be compared against requirements and tasks. In itself, TestComplete - like most test automation tools - will be unable to deliver this, but in combination with a management solution TestComplete can contribute information towards a traceability mapping.

Comment: No it won't solve our purpose. We are instrumenting our js files and then trying to measure coverage by running UI tests using testcomplete. But it didnt work with istanbul.

Comment: @ShravanKumar - if TestComplete runs on the Istanbul instrumented version of the application, are metrics not generated by Istanbul? If need be, you could add "istanbul appname" as a Tested Application in TestComplete, and execute it within your TestComplete tests.